# Map doesn't draw after first start up app without internet connection in new android map api

Tags: android, google-maps

I am now using MapFragment from new google map api v2. Everything works fine except when I first start up my application without internet then when the internet came back and I openned the map again, the map keep showing blank.

Can anyone help me to solve out this problem? this problem also can be found in the sample map app from google.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.test"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
<permission
    android:name="com.example.mapdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.mapdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<!-- Maps API needs OpenGL ES 2.0. -->
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="[map_key]" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.test.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.test;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    map:uiCompass="false"
    map:uiZoomControls="false" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please can you post your manifest file?

Comment: mainfest file has been added.

Comment: @dada..you missed inserting your API key in your manifest.xml ; Here is '<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="[map_key]" />
' Please replace [map_key] with your map key.

Comment: @dada..To get your API key, you don't need to create the new Google Maps API key in order to test your project, Just use the default provided API key, which is shown as "Key for browser apps (with referers) "in your Google APIs Console.

Comment: in fact, I alreadly have my working api key in my project, but the problem still exist. After some search, it seems like it is a bug based on this issue report http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4817

Answer (score 0):

Map activity does not work on a emulator. Also it does not run unless you export the application with a valid keystore. And lastly the correct mapAPI key on the manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a bug of Google Service. They have already fixed it in the new Google play service. 
You need to update your Google play service and api in your Android SDK. Then try to import the updated Google play service library into your project.
Recompile your project. I think it will work.